# Why is creating very large array faster?

Tags: javascript

Why is

```
const arr = new Array(1000000000);
```

way faster than

```
const arr = new Array(1000000);
```

?

I am not saying that the larger, the faster but there is something happening that I can not explain when length is higher than 1 million. This does not happen in Firefox.

https://jsperf.com/large-array-vs-smaller-array

Comment: I don't know the answer but maybe it's faster to allocate entire blocks of memory rather than smaller chunks.

Comment: They're almost exactly the same in Firefox. I suspect it has to do with some heuristic in the runtime system.

Comment: Obviously @GerardoFurtado... I never said "the larger the array the faster" :p

Comment: @httpete Regarding your edit: it's way, way faster on Safari as well, not only on Chrome. And no, I don't have an answer, why do you ask? This is just the *comments* section.

Comment: [take a look here](http://codeabitwiser.com/2015/01/high-performance-javascript-arrays-pt1/) in the section "Large JavaScript Arrays in Chrome V8" and also [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/)